# How can I move a figure "in a section"?

Tags: floats, subcaption

Actually I made a code, and I want to make my figures in (below) Introduction.

But the results is like this:
[image]
How can I make the figure in Introduction?? (Below the 1.Introducition)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\usepackage[left=40mm,right=40mm,top=40mm,bottom=40mm,a4paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,kotex}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{times}  
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsbsy} 
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{curve2e}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.6}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\counterwithin{equation}{section}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}







\renewcommand\refname{\centerline{References}}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}

\begin{document}



\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\numberwithin{thm}{section}
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}
\numberwithin{cor}{section}
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}
\numberwithin{lem}{section}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
\numberwithin{prop}{section}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{de}{Definition}
\numberwithin{de}{section}

\newtheorem{ex}{Example}
\numberwithin{ex}{section}

\newtheorem*{rmk}{Remark}


\setlength{\paperwidth}{40mm}
\setlength{\paperheight}{40mm}

Why



\section{Introduction}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{4.jpg}
    \label{fig:first}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{5.jpg}
    
    \label{fig:second}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Canonical forms are the same.}
\label{fig:figures}
\end{figure}



Come on
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You want this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
    Why
    
    \section{Introduction}
    
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
            \label{fig:first}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
            \label{fig:second}
        \end{subfigure}
        
        \caption{Canonical forms are the same.}
        \label{fig:figures}
    \end{figure}
    
    Come on
\end{document}
```

Also, please try to provide a proper minimal working example next time

Comment: I am really sorry because I thought it was a problem of userpackage..... but maybe it is not. I have a question, though, what is difference between  \begin{figure}[H] and  \begin{figure}[h]??

Comment: @JAEMTO, very big! `H` prevent floats to float, `h` will itry to show image where is inserted (if there is suficient space). However, never use just `h`, beter is `ht` or `htb`, ... which enable that in case, that at point of inserting is not sufficient space, float will move to the top of the next page.

Comment: `H` is provided by the `float` package. You can read all about it in the [doc](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/float).

Comment: I didnt know [H] command, it looks really useful. Thanks!